# Finding the variance of hat check experiment

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

This is the hat check experiment with 3 hats except the outcomes

${1,2,3}$

${1,3,2}$

${2,1,3}$

${3,2,1}$

Have probability $1/5$ and the rest are $1/10$

I have to know the variance on N, which measures the number of people who get their own hats.

$1,2,3   N = 3$

${1,3,2} N = 1$

${2,1,3}N = 1$

${3,2,1}N = 1$

So I know that the $ E(N) = 3 * \frac{1}{5}  + 1 * \frac{1}{5} + 1 * \frac{1}{5} + 1 * \frac{1}{5} $

$E(N) = \frac{6}{5}$

Now to find V(N) I know several methods but none of them work and I am not sure what is the best one to use. I tried the lengthy and time consuming and error prone method of

$\sum{(X(w) - m)^2P(w)}$

where m is the E(N), P(w) is the probability of a specific outcome and X(w) is a specific outcome. I can't get this to work. It seems straightforward.

$ V(N) =  (3 - \frac{6}{5})^2*\frac{1}{5}  (1 - \frac{6}{5})^2*\frac{1}{5}(1 - \frac{6}{5})^2*\frac{1}{5}(1 - \frac{6}{5})^2*\frac{1}{5} $

This is way wrong, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, the simplest way to compute the variance of a random variable $X$ is by using the fact that 
$$\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2.$$

You have already computed $E(N)$. The calculation of $E(N^2)$ is done in the same way. We get $E(N^2)=\frac{1}{5}(3^2+1^2+1^2+1^2)$.

Comment: How would I do this if I was asked to find N and Z, where Z is if N is even?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The random variable $Z$ has been incompletely described. Is it $1$ if $N$ is even and $0$ otherwise? And what is it about $Z$ that we want to find? The mean? The variance? Perhaps a covariance that involves $N$ and $Z$?

Comment: Sorry I just made it up to make an example of doing a variance with two random variables. I want to know the Variance of N + Z so V(N + Z) like in the example above I do not think I can simply use that formula without altering it for two random variables.

Comment: For the variance of a sum of (not independent) random variables, you will want to compute the covariance, so you will need $E(NZ)-E(N)E(Z)$. If you have an explicit question, probably it is best to ask it separately.